# git server information or ascii on remote operations (clone)

Tags: git, ascii, splash-screen, git-clone

How can I configure my git server to display additional information or ascii art on remote operations such as clone ?

An example would be on [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exe-s-store.aspx) and is shown below.

```
F:\>git clone https://myserver/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/Proj 
Username for 'https://myserver': domain\username 
Password for 'https://domain\username@myserver': 
remote: 
remote:                    fTfs 
remote:                  fSSSSSSSs 
remote:                fSSSSSSSSSS 
remote: TSSf         fSSSSSSSSSSSS 
remote: SSSSSF     fSSSSSSST SSSSS 
remote: SSfSSSSSsfSSSSSSSt   SSSSS 
remote: SS  tSSSSSSSSSs      SSSSS 
remote: SS   fSSSSSSST       SSSSS 
remote: SS fSSSSSFSSSSSSf    SSSSS 
remote: SSSSSST    FSSSSSSFt SSSSS 
remote: SSSSt        FSSSSSSSSSSSS 
remote:                FSSSSSSSSSS 
remote:                  FSSSSSSs 
remote:                    FSFs    (TM) 
remote: 
remote:  Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Foundation Server 
remote: 
Receiving objects: 100% (6781/6781), 47.12 MiB | 32.56 MiB/s, done. 
Resolving deltas: 100% (4553/4553), done. 
Checking connectivity... done
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as a git wrapper on the rmeote server which would:

- detect the clone operation
- echo the extra-information first (stdout or stderr should be forwarded back to the client), like your ascii-art.
- call the actual `git clone`.