# How to send custom messages from git server to remote on clone?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-server

When we clone a repository hosted in Visual Studio Team Services, we see the VS ASCII logo:

```
> git clone TargetUrl TargetDir
Cloning into 'TargetDir'...
remote:
remote:                    fTfs
remote:                  fSSSSSSSs
remote:                fSSSSSSSSSS
remote: TSSf         fSSSSSSSSSSSS
remote: SSSSSF     fSSSSSSST SSSSS
remote: SSfSSSSSsfSSSSSSSt   SSSSS
remote: SS  tSSSSSSSSSs      SSSSS
remote: SS   fSSSSSSST       SSSSS
remote: SS fSSSSSFSSSSSSf    SSSSS
remote: SSSSSST    FSSSSSSFt SSSSS
remote: SSSSt        FSSSSSSSSSSSS
remote:                FSSSSSSSSSS
remote:                  FSSSSSSs
remote:                    FSFs    (TM)
remote:
remote:  Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Foundation Server
remote:
Receiving objects:  ##% (##/###), ###.## MiB | ###.## KiB/s
```

- How can one configure this kind of custom message in self-hosted git server?
- Does server know whether the caller's shell / tty has colors enabled?
- Could these messages be modified per repository?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343463/git-server-information-or-ascii-on-remote-operations-clone